# Why do train companies require two hours to deliver your ticket to the machine?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

It makes it very difficult for me to book online and I end up buying the tickets from the machine itself

[image]

Comment: To be fair, there are very few cases when you can get a better deal from a website than from a machine, when you are purchasing a ticket for same day travel. There are exceptions because the machines don't sell most kinds of complex tickets, but then again neither do the websites.

Comment: The answer is likely to be a boring technical synchronization concern. The back end for these systems is often surprisingly backwards. Probably the ticket machines only get an updated list of what tickets to print once per hour.

Comment: Online? At that speed, they probably synchronize the machines by having someone going to them in a G-Wiz.

Comment: They do **not** require you to wait 2 hours. They are simply teeling you: email does not provide any guarantee about instant delivery, so it *may happen* that it takes *up to* two hours. Then 99.9% of the time you receive the ticket in 5 minutes...  Note that the email system doesn't provide any kind of guarantee about delivery, which means that there are situations where due to issues with the servers/connections the email could have been dropped altogether and will never arrive... if you want to be sure of delivery (and authentication/integrity) you have to use certified email

Comment: The title of this question is about a ticket order delivered "to the machine", where there are certainly system delays to contend with, as @Calchas notes. But the screenshot seems to be for Virgin's eticket-by-email service, which doesn't involve dealing with a ticket issuing machine at the station - you just get a ticket sent to you to print or put on a phone. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @Andrew both require two hours, not only with Virgin but other companies as well

Comment: Perhaps more important - why is the second person in the queue a space alien wearing a wig?!?

Comment: If nothing goes wrong, you can pick up tickets within about a minute of ordering them online. I once booked tickets online while stood next to a ticket machine which didn't sell what I needed, whilst looking at a long queue for the manned booking office window, and collected the tickets pretty much immediately! May not always work though, hence the 2 hour caveat

Comment: @Ulkoma They *say* it can take up to 2 hours, but does it actually take that long? I would expect 99%+ of all tickets to be delivered within a manner of minutes. Unless you actually experience hour-long delivery times whenever you order tickets this is a rather dishonest question.

Comment: Interestingly East Midland Trains says you can collect within 15 minutes on their website but when you get the confirmation email it says 2 hours.

Comment: @Calchas but where there are collection machines or e-tickets you can avoid the queue for the ticket-purchase machines.  These queues can be long enough to make you miss the train if (for example) one of 2 machines is down.

Comment: @ChrisH I think in most cases the ticket collection and ticket purchase machines are actually the same now?

Comment: @Calchas I mostly travel through Bristol Parkway where they're different

Comment: I have several times successfully bought tickets online from Kings Cross to Edinburgh no more than 10 minutes before picking them up. I happened to use Trainline, but I expect all services are similar. Not guaranteed to work, but in practice it does.

Comment: I just bought a ticket from East Midlands Trains. The website says the ticket can be picked up from the machine in 15 minutes, although the confirmation email says two hours.

Comment: Along the chain of delivery they have a component that is outside of their control (ie imposed by regulation/law).
Or they are themselves protected by regulation/law and they don't give a crap.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

All they are doing there is **setting an expectation**, there is no specific meaning, technical or otherwise, to 'two hours' other than perhaps an internal calculation that 99.99% of e-tickets are issues within two hours.

They do this to hopefully prevent people from calling 5-10 minutes after making the booking asking where their tickets are.  Calls are relatively expensive to handle and a lot of effort is put into making them unnecessary.

Maybe tickets are issued in batch, maybe not, but it really doesn't matter.  If you don't get your ticket within 121 minutes, there's probably something wrong.

Determining and setting an expectation like this (SLA) is very common and in no way unique to train tickets.

Comment: Part of my job involves technical administration of email servers. I concur with this answer, especially the first paragraph. The email is likely sent out immediately but in times of high server load emails are often given low priority which can cause them to be delayed and sit temporarily in a mail queue. The two hour estimate should be seen as a disclaimer for the unlikely event where your email takes more than a couple of minutes

Comment: I've done my share of SLA analysis as well.

Comment: +1 to this. As someone in the field, this is absolutely correct. Its not always some nefarious technology headache - often it is business setting expectations for customers in order to have a standard against which to measure efficiency and performance; and as the efficiency/process changes, so does the standard against which the average is calculated.

Comment: Minor typo: *e-tickets are issue(**d**) within two hours*

Comment: 2hr is long enough to start up the backup server and process all outstanding transactions if a server should fail.....   Not having to have "HOT" 24/7 operations, so allowing severs to be rebooted etc saves a LOT of money.

Comment: What does SLA stand for?

Comment: Service Level Agreement.

Comment: I've collected tickets about an hour after online booking before, so I'd take it as setting expectations rather than a hard limit.  That said, I'd not book tickets on the assumption that you'll *definitely* get them in <2hrs

Comment: They don't do this for fail cases.  Even though the ticket could and may actually be issued in minutes, they don't want to commit to that.